# How to implement a Lottie splash screens in Vue App

Tags: cordova, vuejs2, capacitor

We are trying to add a json file from Lottie to our VUe App, the app loads and show the icon as splash image and move to the main activity , but never show the json file which is hosted in lottie files to show up on the screen.

We had added the Lottie prefrence in the capacitor.config

```
{
  "appId": "com.weather.app",
  "appName": "weatherapp",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "webDir": "www",
  "server": {
    "androidScheme": "https",
    "url": "http://192.168.1.7:9500"
  },
  "plugins": {
    "PushNotifications": {
      "presentationOptions": [
        "badge",
        "sound",
        "alert"
      ]
    },
    "GoogleAuth": {
      "scopes": [
        "profile",
        "email"
      ],
      "serverClientId": "",
      "forceCodeForRefreshToken": true
    },
    "SplashScreen": {
      "androidScaleType": "CENTER_CROP"
    }
  },
  "cordova": {
    "preferences": {
      "LottieRemoteEnabled": "true",
      "LottieFullScreen": "true",
      "LottieHideAfterAnimationEnd": "true",
      "LottieAnimationLocation": "https://lottie.host/example.json"
    }
  }
}
```

Apart from above we did not make any changes, by default the app using the cordova splash screen plugin to show up the splash screen.

We had installed the cordova-plugin-lottie-splashscreen via npm (visual studio code)